# Android How to Remove Text Shadow?

Tags: android, android-widget, textview

I Have an android program with a bunch of text views. Initially, all of these views have no shadow.

when I press a specific toggle button, I want theses textViews to stand out.

Ideally, I wanted to add a text shadow glow effect to them. this I have
successfully done without a problem with textView.setShadowLayer(radius, dx, dy, color)

The problem is, if I press the same toggle button again (which makes the shadows appear), 
I need to remove the shadows so the text isn't highlighted anymore.

I have tried to set the shadow layer to radius 0 and transparent colors #00FFFFFF, #00000000, and colors #FFFFFFFF, #FF000000. However, none of these set the textView back
to the original way it appeared.

any ideas on how to remove the shadow. (I don't really have to remove it, i just want the text to appear the same way as before adding it)

the main goal is to use the toggle button to turn on/off text highlighting for specific textViews and I am open to other methods than using a shadow. Ideally I would like to use a shadow, but any other ideas to highlight the text are fine.

(this part was appended after the answer I received with textLayer.setShadow(0,0,0,0);

i am using this style for textView in the layout xml

```
<style name="second">
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/buttonBabyBlue</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/second_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:lines">1</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/baseGray</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dip</item> 
    <item name="android:layout_weight">8.5</item> 
    <item name="android:gravity">bottom|left</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">bottom</item>
</style>
```

when i press the button which makes the view have a shadow

```
text.setShadowLayer(GLOW_RADIUS, GLOW_DX, GLOW_DY, R.drawable.buttonBabyBlue);
text.setTextColor(R.drawable.baseGray);
```

then to remove the shadow

```
text.setShadowLayer(0, 0, 0, 0);
text.setTextColor(R.drawable.buttonBabyBlue);
```

that is annoying i have pictures to show and uploaded them but 
they won't let me show them for fear of spam

Answer (score 9):

Call `textview.setShadowLayer(0,0,0,0)` to clear the shadow layer.

---

There is a `clearShadowLayer()` method in `Paint` class, but internally that too calls the `setShadowLayer` with all zero parameters. So seems like that won't work for you.

The only other way I can think of is by overriding the `onDraw` method. Maintain a `TextPaint` object that is set with the shadow parameters.

```
@Override
void setShadowLayer(.....) {                  // do not call super
    paintWithShadowLayer.setShadowLayer(....); // the other with shadow layer set
}

@Override
void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    ...
    if (bToggleON) {
         canvas.drawText(text, index, count, x, y, paintWithShadowLayer);
    } else {
         canvas.drawText(text, index, count, x, y, getPaint());
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: That didn't work, the shadow is removed, however the text view is now a darker color than its original showing..

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I guess I am going to have to find some other way of "highlighting" these text views. I have two other ideas, 1. change the background to something else and back, and 2. using a FrameLayout, place some low alpha text views of the same thing over the existing ones and then removing them somehow, first approach probably won't look very good, and the second will probably  be difficult to work on various screen sizes, and will stress performance because of the amount of extra views

Comment: I have to clarify, I was unaware of the fact that a setting a text color to an actual color resource vs drawable resource are vastly different, i thought the drawable wsa just a color with an alpha value, but that isn't the case... the setShadowLayer(0,0,0,0) did work when colors/drawables are used correctly

Answer (score 2):

```
textView.getPaint().clearShadowLayer();
textView.invalidate();
```

This worked for me.